# Unable to setState using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

This piece of code to setState for an object doesnot work for me.

```
  const [showCommentPopup, setShowCommentPopup] = useState({ showPopUp: false, commentText: '',type: ''} as CommentPopUp);


                             <Button
                              aria-label="addComment"
                              onClick={() => setShowCommentPopup({showPopUp: true, type: expenseType, commentText: comments || ''}) 
                              }
                              data-testid="add-comment"
                            >
```

Comment: Please be more specific: 'does not work for me' is pretty vague. How would you know (based only on the code you posted) if it does work?

Comment: what is not working, be more specific. You can console.log(showCommentPopup) and see if it will change onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your `as CommentPopUp`. Why did you need that?

Comment: She is using typescript. The correct way would be `useState<CommentPopUp>({...})`. Otherwise the type couldn't be inferred from the plain object.

Comment: Ah my fault. Didn't know that was typescript! Thanks for pointing that out